# Hyperlink to downlaod CSV opens when link is pasted manually but not when clicked

Tags: php, html, firebase, csv, file

I've created a unique front end portal for two businesses to exchange files between them. To upload the files I am currently getting the file contents by using base64_encode to encode the contents to send to the database and then decode when calling the contents.

Files like PDF work fine, I am able to upload and then download through my portal through clinking on url, however, using this method there is an issue with CSV files. On clicking the hyperlink, a new tab opens up (i have target="_blank") then closes immediately, however, if I copy the hyperlink URL and paste it, the files and their contents download fine.

The following is the URL hyperlink I click that downloads the file:

```
echo("<a target='_blank' href='http://URL/CC/downloadDoc?fileName=$fileNameO&bfFor=$bfOrganisation'>".$fileNameO."</a>");
```

and this is a snippet of the downloadDoc.php code:

```
$downdecode = base64_decode($donwloadFile);

$newstring = substr($fileName, -3);

if ($newstring == 'pdf'){
  header('Content-type:application/pdf');
    header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$fileName.'"');

    header('content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges:bytes');
    echo $downdecode;
    readfile($downdecode);
  }else if($newstring == 'csv'){
    

        
        //header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
        
        $f = fopen('php://output', 'a'); // Configure fopen to write to the output buffer

        fwrite($f, $downdecode);

        fclose($f);

  }
```

I don't know why this isn't working when I click the URL as when entering it manually it works, so if anyone can help me out that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is the headers you are setting for the CSV. Do you want the "Save As" dialog to open, or do you want it to show in the browser?

I just whipped together this simple class for serving files, I tested locally and it appears to be opening in new tab for all filetypes it supports. If you want CSV files to appear as a Save as Dialog instead of appear in the browser, change the Content-Type to `text/csv` and the Content-Disposition to `attachment` instead of inline.

To call, just do:

```
$serve = new ServeFile('filename', 'encoded contents');
$serve->serve();
```

**serveFile.class.php**

```
<?php

class ServeFile
{
    private $filePath = '';
    private $urlPath = '';
    private $extension = '';
    private $serveFunction = '';
    private $encodedContents = '';

    public function __construct($filePath = null, $encodedContents = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($filePath))
            $this->setFile($filePath, $encodedContents);
    }

    public function setFile($filePath, $encodedContents = null)
    {
        $this->filePath = $filePath;
        $this->urlPath .= pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $this->extension = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $this->serveFunction = $this->map($this->extension);
        
        if (!is_null($encodedContents))
            $this->encodedContents = $encodedContents;
    }

    protected function serveHeaders($headers)
    {
        foreach ($headers as $header)
            header($header);
    }

    protected function map($extension)
    {
        $map = [
            'json' => 'serveJSON',
            'pdf' => 'servePDF',
            'csv' => 'serveCSV',
            'jpg' => 'serveJPEG'
        ];

        if (isset($map[$extension]))
            return $map[$extension];

        return 'serveGeneric';
    }

    protected function serveGeneric()
    {
        echo $this->contents;
    }

    protected function serveJSON()
    {
        $this->serveHeaders(['Content-Type: application/json']);
        echo $this->contents;
    }

    protected function servePDF()
    {
        $this->serveHeaders([
            'Content-Type: application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$this->urlPath.'.pdf"',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary',
            'Accept-Ranges: bytes'
        ]);
        echo $this->contents;
    }

    protected function serveCSV()
    {
        $this->serveHeaders([
            'Content-Type: text/plain',
            'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$this->urlPath.'.csv"',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8'
        ]);
        echo $this->contents;
    }

    protected function serveJPEG()
    {
        $this->serveHeaders(['Content-Type: image/jpeg']);
        echo $this->contents;
    }

    public function serve()
    {

        if (!empty($this->encodedContents))
            $this->contents = base64_decode($this->encodedContents);
        else    
            $this->contents = file_get_contents($this->filePath);

        call_user_func_array([$this, $this->serveFunction],[]);
    }
}
```

The test script is as follows

**serve.php**

```
<?php

include 'ServeFile.class.php';

if (!isset($_GET['file']))
    die();

$encodedContents = null;
if ($_GET['file'] == 'encoded.jpg')
    $encodedContents = file_get_contents('encoded_jpg.txt');

$serveFile = new ServeFile($_GET['file'], $encodedContents);
$serveFile->serve();
```

**index.html**

```
<a href="serve.php?file=test.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a><br><br>
<a href="serve.php?file=test.json" target="_blank">JSON</a><br><br>
<a href="serve.php?file=test.csv" target="_blank">CSV</a><br><br>
<a href="serve.php?file=test.jpg" target="_blank">JPG</a><br><br>
<a href="serve.php?file=encoded.jpg" target="_blank">Encoded JPG</a><br><br>
```